# Generating layouts with Prism (Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, layout, prism

I'm new to Prism and have a conceptual question.

What I want to build is a Silverlight app that can load its layout (and the modules that are used) from a config file. Imagine I have a number of modules (e.g. a Chart, a Treeview and a Newsticker) and I want to use my config file to determine which of those are visible in my app and also where they are located on screen.

So if I want to have an app with just a Graph and a Treeview but not a Newsticker, would it be enough to just create an XAML file that contains views to those two modules? Would this XAML file be the shell?

Could I then have different XAML files/shells/config files to "generate" different looking applications at startup?

I don't need to switch layouts at runtime, I just want to be able to easily configure my application to use a different set of modules. I would appreciate pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some approaches that I found:

http://blog.roundthecampfire.net/2011/10/creating-composable-ui-with-f-and-prism.html

http://www.dotnetpatterns.net/content/147-Lesson-2-Prism-creating-a-dynamic-region-layout-with-templates